# OpenSSL Error: lib(128):capi_rsa_priv_enc:function not supported in client Auth

Tags: https, openssl, curl

My scripts to sign file via API was working properly fine when my previous server setup was Ubuntu 20.04 and openssl version is 1.1.1b.

But after upgrade, I am getting this issue. Client environment is same before and after the server upgrade.

Now
Current Server Env :

```
    Ubuntu 22..04  
    Openssl 3.0.2  
    Apache 2.4.52  
    SSL x509 certificate is installed on the Apache Server
```

Client Env:

```
    Windows 2016  
    Curl 7.78.0
    openssl 1.1.1f
```

Below command has been executed to sign a file via web API running on Server over https.

curl.exe --request POST --cacert "ca.crt" --cert "user.crt" --engine capi --key-type ENG --key "user.key" --verbose -L "https://webapi:port" --header "content-type: multipart/form-data" --form "file=@file.txt" --output "out_file.txt"

### tailed output:

...
..

[5 bytes data]

- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Hello request (0):
  { [4 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
  } [232 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
  { [117 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
  { [1319 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
  { [556 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
  { [1979 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
  { [4 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
  } [4292 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
  } [37 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, internal error (592):
  } [2 bytes data]
- OpenSSL SSL_read: error:8006F074:lib(128):capi_rsa_priv_enc:function not supported, errno 0
  0 82.4M    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
- Closing connection 0
  curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: error:8006F074:lib(128):capi_rsa_priv_enc:function not supported, errno 0

I tried to disable tlsv1.2 and tlsv1.3 on server ssl.conf but still issue remains the same.

My understanding on openssl and x509 certificate troubleshooting is limited.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be related to CAPI engine use. My suspicion is that the OpenSSL version that is being used does not support the "capi_rsa_priv_enc" function [Openssl 1.1.1f capi_rsa_priv_enc link](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/fe824ce0c5d51e7e7cf36c31db6c49c1c0c04a25/engines/e_capi.c#L811).

<strike>And it seems that curl is compiled with an older version of OpenSSL that does support the function.</strike>

Check what version curl uses:

```
curl --version
```

Try to recompile the curl with OpenSSL 1.1.1f on the Windows client and check if the error is fixed.

EDIT:

OpenSSL with CAPI and Mutual Auth at client side will not work if the OpenSSL server version is >=1.1.1. [TLS 1.2 won't work on Windows](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/12859)

The older CAPI engine won't support RSA-PSS for both TLS 1.2 and 1.3. And as per your server configuration, it uses OpenSSL-3, which will cause negotiation to fail.

Also, the OpenSSL-3 version won't support the CAPI engine anyway, so my recommendation is to upgrade the client system to use the next-gen Windows Crypto API for accessing the WebAPI.

You can also look into [openssl-cng-engine](https://github.com/rticommunity/openssl-cng-engine)